# Find Key Word in a column that matches a word in a two column Table and return the value in second column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table with values
ex:
Apple    1
orange   2
blue     3
In column C I have sentences and would like to find word from table (ex apple) and return the value in the second column (1) with a formula.

I tried =INDEX(f6:G10,MATCH(c6,f6:B10,1),MATCH(c6,f5:G5,1))

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you for the views.
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$4:$G$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$4:$F$7,A13)),0),$G$4:$G$7),"")

Comment: How do I show as closed?  I can't vote for my own post.